# Stuck on some symbolic manipulation of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm stuck trying to understand the symbolic manipulations happening below. The math occurs in a proof that positive semidefinite matrices are necessarily singular - A is a positive semidefinite matrix, i.e. symmetric - A = A'. I'm just interested in the steps between the two lines - could somebody with decent linear algebra help me out ?

[image: Matrix algebra]

Answer (score 3):

Just open up the brackets, and use $(X+Y)^T =X^T+Y^T, \ \ (tA)^T=tA^T, \ \ (Ax)^T=x^TA^T$, and also $A^T=A$.

Comment: Thanks! I spent about 10 minutes staring at your answer trying to figure out how (tA)' = t A' could possibly be true. Then I realised that you were reading t as a constant, which is the only way the question makes any sense - I'd misread it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, $t$ is a real number